# Automatically resolving dependencies when compiling using Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, roslyn

I'm currently writing an application that currently loads a project via Roslyn's workspace API, turns a specified C# file into a syntax tree then creates an in memory assembly form it, then eventually extracts the IL.

This is all working fine, however as soon as I reference any external libraries within the said C# file, the compilation fails as Roslyn doesn't know where to resolve those references.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm currently doing:

```
MetadataReference[] metaDatareferences = {
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Uri).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(DynamicAttribute).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(AssemblyMetadata).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
};

var sourceLanguage = new CSharpLanguage();

var syntaxTree = sourceLanguage.ParseText(sourceCode, SourceCodeKind.Regular);
var options = new CSharpCompilationOptions(
    OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary,
    optimizationLevel: OptimizationLevel.Debug,
    allowUnsafe: true
);

CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("ExampleAssembly", options: options);

var stream = new MemoryStream();
var result = compilation.
    AddReferences(metaDatareferences)
    .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree)
    .Emit(stream);

// Success is false
if (!emitResult.Success)
{
    foreach (var diagnostic in emitResult.Diagnostics)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(diagnostic.ToString());
    }
}
```

The output of the `Debug.WriteLine` is:

```
(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MediatR' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
(9,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Mediator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

And the file my Roslyn project is reading is simply this:

```
using MediatR;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mediator = new Mediator(null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, does Roslyn provide an API for automatically load any dependencies a file may have? I was hopeful that the Roslyn workspace would allow this to be done, but I've not been able to find anything.

Comment: Are you sure it's due to not being able to load references, and not e.g. some syntax error? Show us the exact compiler error.

Comment: I've updated my question to include the error output and the file I'm reading.

Comment: so, you're hoping the `using MediatR;` directive would resolve your lib? That's why you have `#r <path>` in CSharpScript. Even `MetadataReferences` need to be resolved, see 
[MetadataReferenceResolver](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/MetadataReference/MetadataReferenceResolver.cs,4d808b77e09b1008). They only way of achieving this I can think of would be to #1 compile, #2 check known errors, try to add references, goto #1. But even that wouldn't work for extension methods etc, that share a namespace...

Comment: @m0sa No, this isn't a C# Script file. My intention is to compile a random C# pulled from a project's workspace.

Comment: @JosephWoodward if you have an existing project (from `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces`) you can just call `(project.GetCompilationAsync()).RemoveSyntaxTrees().AddSyntaxTrees(yourSourceTree)`... Obviously that won't work as soon as you source references anything else inside your project.

Comment: When you say you are loading a file "from a project", do you have a .csproj or project.json or something around to look at?

Comment: You are missing a reference. It's not about not being able to load references, it's about not having them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the MediatR console project is a `project.json` project, then you can use `ProjectJsonWorkspace` from `"Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Workspaces": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"`. You can point it at your `project.json` and get a `Compilation` object, this will have done all the hard work for you of getting the project references, file references, etc... Then you can just emit your IL from here.

Here is an example:

```
var compilation = new ProjectJsonWorkspace(@"PathToYour\project.json").CurrentSolution.Projects.First().GetCompilationAsync().Result;

var stream = new MemoryStream();
var emitResult = compilation.Emit(stream);
```

Or if you need total control, you could continue to use `CSharpCompilation.Create`, copying in what you need from the `compilation` object here, and passing in a `SyntaxTree`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect, `ProjectJsonWorkspace` is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!